# Paste string in system

Tags: r, bash, paste

Within R how could I try to use this unix command

```
printf "%s\t" NAMES n{1..1600} >file_o
```

Trying

`system(paste("printf \"%s\t\" NAMES n{1..1600} >file_o"))`

causes no message, but it does not create the same output.  The file is just

```
NAMES   n{1..1600}
```

when it should be

```
NAMES n1 n2 (/t in betwen up to the max number )
```

the comments indicate that this might have somethign to do with the OS - on ubuntu it doesnt work neither on Debian

the output of printen

```
 [1] "LESSOPEN=| /usr/bin/lesspipe %s"                                                                                
 [2] "R_UNZIPCMD=/usr/bin/unzip"                                                                                      
 [3] "USER=katoui"                                                                                                   
 [4] "LANGUAGE=en_GB:en"                                                                                              
 [5] "UPSTART_INSTANCE="                                                                                              
 [6] "XDG_SEAT=seat0"                                                                                                 
 [7] "TEXTDOMAIN=im-config"                                                                                           
 [8] "SSH_AGENT_PID=1272"                                                                                             
 [9] "COMPIZ_CONFIG_PROFILE=ubuntu"                                                                                   
[10] "LD_LIBRARY_PATH=/usr/lib/R/lib:/usr/lib/x86_64-linux-gnu:/usr/lib/jvm/java-7-openjdk-amd64/jre/lib/amd64/server"
[11] "SHLVL=1"                                                                                                        
[12] "HOME=/home/katou"                                                                                             
[13] "QT4_IM_MODULE=ibus"                                                                                             
[14] "DESKTOP_SESSION=ubuntu"                                                                                         
[15] "R_LIBS_SITE=/usr/local/lib/R/site-library:/usr/lib/R/site-library:/usr/lib/R/library"                           
[16] "GTK_MODULES=overlay-scrollbar:unity-gtk-module"                                                                 
[17] "XDG_SEAT_PATH=/org/freedesktop/DisplayManager/Seat0"                                                            
[18] "R_BROWSER=xdg-open"                                                                                             
[19] "PAGER=/usr/bin/pager"                                                                                           
[20] "INSTANCE=Unity"                                                                                                 
[21] "DBUS_SESSION_BUS_ADDRESS=unix:abstract=/tmp/dbus-hR5PKeEWoO"                                                    
[22] "R_SYSTEM_ABI=linux,gcc,gxx,gfortran,?"                                                                          
[23] "COLORTERM=gnome-terminal"                                                                                       
[24] "GNOME_KEYRING_CONTROL=/run/user/1000/keyring-FBpib0"                                                            
[25] "UBUNTU_MENUPROXY=1"                                                                                             
[26] "QT_QPA_PLATFORMTHEME=appmenu-qt5"                                                                               
[27] "MANDATORY_PATH=/usr/share/gconf/ubuntu.mandatory.path"                                                          
[28] "IM_CONFIG_PHASE=1"                                                                                              
[29] "SESSIONTYPE=gnome-session"                                                                                      
[30] "UPSTART_JOB=unity-settings-daemon"                                                                              
[31] "LOGNAME=katou"                                                                                                
[32] "GTK_IM_MODULE=ibus"                                                                                             
[33] "TAR=/bin/tar"                                                                                                   
[34] "WINDOWID=67112765"                                                                                              
[35] "DEFAULTS_PATH=/usr/share/gconf/ubuntu.default.path"                                                             
[36] "R_LIBS_USER=~/R/x86_64-pc-linux-gnu-library/3.1"                                                                
[37] "XDG_SESSION_ID=c1"                                                                                              
[38] "TERM=xterm"                                                                                                     
[39] "COLUMNS=80"                                                                                                     
[40] "GNOME_DESKTOP_SESSION_ID=this-is-deprecated"                                                                    
[41] "R_ARCH="                                                                                                        
[42] "R_PAPERSIZE_USER=a4"                                                                                            
[43] "PATH=/opt/texbin:/usr/local/sbin:/usr/local/bin:/usr/sbin:/usr/bin:/sbin:/bin:/usr/games:/usr/local/games"      
[44] "SELINUX_INIT=YES"                                                                                               
[45] "GDM_LANG=en_GB"                                                                                                 
[46] "R_BZIPCMD=/bin/bzip2"                                                                                           
[47] "R_INCLUDE_DIR=/usr/share/R/include"                                                                             
[48] "XDG_SESSION_PATH=/org/freedesktop/DisplayManager/Session0"                                                      
[49] "XDG_RUNTIME_DIR=/run/user/1000"                                                                                 
    [50] "R_SESSION_TMPDIR=/tmp/Rtmpg8bGY1"
51] "DISPLAY=:0"                                                                                                     
[52] "LANG=en_GB.UTF-8"                                                                                               
[53] "XDG_CURRENT_DESKTOP=Unity"                                                                                      
[54] "XMODIFIERS=@im=ibus"                                                                                            
[55] "XAUTHORITY=/home/maurice/.Xauthority"                                                                           
[56] "XDG_GREETER_DATA_DIR=/var/lib/lightdm-data/maurice"                                                             
[57] "SSH_AGENT_LAUNCHER=upstart"                                                                                     
[58] "SSH_AUTH_SOCK=/run/user/1000/keyring-FBpib0/ssh"                                                                
[59] "R_GZIPCMD=/bin/gzip"                                                                                            
[60] "SED=/bin/sed"                                                                                                   
[61] "SHELL=/bin/bash"                                                                                                
[62] "LN_S=ln -s"                                                                                                     
[63] "QT_ACCESSIBILITY=1"                                                                                             
[64] "GDMSESSION=ubuntu"                                                                                              
[65] "R_PDFVIEWER=/usr/bin/xdg-open"                                                                                  
[66] "LESSCLOSE=/usr/bin/lesspipe %s %s"                                                                              
[67] "UPSTART_EVENTS=started starting"                                                                                
[68] "R_TEXI2DVICMD=/usr/bin/texi2dvi"                                                                                
[69] "GPG_AGENT_INFO=/run/user/1000/keyring-FBpib0/gpg:0:1"                                                           
[70] "UPSTART_SESSION=unix:abstract=/com/ubuntu/upstart-session/1000/1191"                                            
[71] "R_HOME=/usr/lib/R"                                                                                              
[72] "TEXTDOMAINDIR=/usr/share/locale/"                                                                               
[73] "R_PRINTCMD=/usr/bin/lpr"                                                                                        
[74] "XDG_VTNR=7"                                                                                                     
[75] "QT_IM_MODULE=ibus"                                                                                              
[76] "R_DOC_DIR=/usr/share/R/doc"                                                                                     
[77] "PWD=/home/ryo"                                                                                              
[78] "R_SHARE_DIR=/usr/share/R/share"                                                                                 
[79] "R_ZIPCMD=/usr/bin/zip"                                                                                          
[80] "CLUTTER_IM_MODULE=xim"                                                                                          
[81] "XDG_CONFIG_DIRS=/etc/xdg/xdg-ubuntu:/usr/share/upstart/xdg:/etc/xdg"                                            
[82] "XDG_DATA_DIRS=/usr/share/ubuntu:/usr/share/gnome:/usr/local/share/:/usr/share/"                                 
[83] "PYTHONPATH=:/usr/lib/python2.7/site-packages"                                                                   
[84] "R_PLATFORM=x86_64-pc-linux-gnu"                                                                                 
[85] "R_PAPERSIZE=letter"                                                                                             
[86] "LINES=24"                                                                                                       
[87] "MAKE=make"                                                                                                      
[88] "VTE_VERSION=3409"                                                                                               
[89] "R_RD4PDF=times,inconsolata,hyper"                                                                               
[90] "JOB=gnome-session"                                                                                              
[91] "EDITOR=vi"
```

Comment: Your code produced the expected result for me. What OS are you on? Are you sure your default shell is bash? If you fun `system('printenv',intern=TRUE)`, what do you see listed under `SHELL=`?

Comment: Of course you could just create the file with R: `writeLines(paste("NAMES",paste0("n", 1:1600, collapse=" ")), "file_o")`

Comment: I am on bash yes...it is strange for me it doesnt work

Comment: @MrFlick for me this prodces a file with NAMES n{1..1600} ...the output i was looking for is NAMES tab n1 tab n2 tab n3 tab ....and that is the pont if i execute l the lien in bash

Comment: I do get the "NAMES\tn1\tn2\tn3..." values in the file. But I tested on my Mac. Again, it would be helpful to know the exact OS you are using and to see the output of  `system('printenv',intern=TRUE)` on your system.

Comment: Tested on Debian 8 / bash and have the same result as ktoui

Comment: oh this is a list with 100 elements..so it is ubuntu 14 and the echo $shell return bin/bash

Comment: But while this is unsatisfactory as such, you still can follow @MrFlick's suggestion

Comment: I have a whole file to create with another couple of lines...so I would completely transform the code...I am using print more than a single time..so it is not really a solution

Comment: `cat()` may be your friend when you are working in R anyway, for the other lines as well. I have been playing around with `system()` and `system2()` for a while now and I don't get anything else but the short file.

Comment: do you think itr worsk with cat?..if that works out i am happy to work with ?

Comment: @MrFlick tried aslos writeLines(paste("NAMES",paste0("n", 1:1600, collapse=" ")), sep="\t", "file_a")
 but then the output is not tab delimi...how do I get the tab between the na?

Comment: just change your `collapse="\t"`

Comment: will that make a trailing tab at the endo f the line..that is not intende?
writeLines(paste("NAMES",paste0("n", 1:1600, collapse=" ", sep = "\t"),sep = "\t"), "file_a1")

Comment: you probably want `paste("NAMES", paste0("n", 1:1600, collapse="\t"))` and no it won't leave a tab at the end

Answer (score 0):

Two alternative ways to get the output are:

```
system('echo -n "NAMES\\\\t" > file_o')
```

and

```
system(' for i in $(seq 0 1600)  ; do printf "n${i}\\\\t" >> file_o ; done')
```